# asp.net core 2.1 json serialization null array is not ignored

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following classes:
FormGroupModel has a list of FormFieldModel which has a list of FieldOptionModel.

```
public class FormGroupModel
{
    public string GroupLabel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FormFieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FormFieldModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }   
    public IEnumerable<FieldOptionModel> Options { get; set; }

}

public class FieldOptionModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

I configured Json serializationsettings in Startup.cs to NullValueHandling.Ignore.  Null values for my other API return values are all ignored as expected.   This object serialization still does not get rid of the Options array when it's empty. I also tried DefaultValueHandling.Ignore but does not work either.  How can I get the Options list to be ignored when empty?

```
[
    {
        "groupLabel": "Basic Information",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "ProjectDescription",
                "label": "Project Description",
                "controlType": "multiline",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "name": "ProjectId",
                "label": "Project Id",
                "controlType": "textfield",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "name": "ProjectName",
                "label": "Project Name",
                "controlType": "textfield",
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "name": "ProjectScope",
                "label": "Project Scope",
                "controlType": "multiline",
                "options": []
            }
```

Comment: "This object serialization still does not get rid of the Options array when it's empty"... I assume you already realise that's because it's empty and that's not the same as being null? Anyway I haven't tried it, but I'd say it might be worth trying with https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#DefaultValueHandling, possibly in combination with the DefaultValueAttribute mentioned, to try and see if will recognise an empty list as a "default" value, and then ignore it. Might not work but from the docs I can't see any other relevant options.

Comment: I did a workaround and looked through the collection to manually set each options that is empty to null.  But an option to ignore null arrays when serializing would be nice.